# Sending byte array from android native service to app

Tags: android, c++, native, stdvector, aidl

Im trying to return a byte array from an android native service(C++) to an android application using AIDL. Im calculating the byte array from two files and trying to split the final array at the client side using the length of byte array of one file.**For Eg  resultFinal= lengthof privKey + privKey + pubKey**

```
   std::ifstream _privKey("/etc/myPrivkey", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        std::vector<uint8_t> _privKeyContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(_privKey)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
         
 std::ifstream _pubKey("/etc/myPubkey", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        std::vector<uint8_t> _pubKeyContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(_pubKey)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
         vector<uint8_t> certFinal;  
      uint8_t keysize=_privKeyContents.size();    Verified this and the keysize is 161
         
      resultFinal.insert(resultFinal.begin(),_pubKeyContents.begin(), _pubKeyContents.end());   
      resultFinal.insert(resultFinal.begin(),_privKeyContents.begin(), _privKeyContents.end());       
      resultFinal.insert(resultFinal.begin(),keysize);
```

I assume at the client side the first element of the byte array will be the size of the _privKeyContents and using that
value i can split the byte array in to two. I was expecting the first element of the byte array to be **161** but instead im getting **-95**

Can someone help me to identify the issue ? or Is my approach is wrong ? Please let me know if there any other input needed from my end

Thanks In advance
Ps: I dont have much idea about C++.

Comment: Which line leads to the output -95? In a vector of `uint8_t` it's actually weird to get a negative value.

Comment: Print all byte values in hexadecimal notation. At sending side and at receiving side.Then you see what you get. Further you could have told us how 161 could equal -95. It has to do with signed and unsigned.

Comment: Im getting -95 at receiving side which is in java. Will print values in hexadecimal notation and see